# Как написать лямбда выражение для данного случая

Tags: c#, visual-basic, visual-studio-2015

Имеется класс на C# оформленный в виде библиотеки и подключен к проекту на VB.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace YandexTranslate
{

    public enum RequestType
    {
        Translate = 0,
        Detect = 1
    }

    public struct TranslateCommand
    {
        public RequestType Type;
        public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters;
        public Func<XElement, string> ResultSelector;
    }

    public class TextTranslationAPI
    {

        private readonly string Url;
        private readonly string Key;
        public TextTranslationAPI(string url, string key)
        {
            Url = url;
            Key = key;
        }

        public TextTranslationAPI() : this(@"https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr/", "trnsl.1.1.XXXXXX")
        { }

        private string GetAction(RequestType type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case RequestType.Detect:
                    return "detect";
                case RequestType.Translate:
                    return "translate";
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }

        public string GetResult(TranslateCommand command)
        {
            string strUrl = Url + GetAction(command.Type) + "?key=" + Key;
            foreach (var parameter in command.Parameters)
                strUrl += "&" + parameter.Key + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameter.Value);
            WebClient webClitnt = new WebClient();
            webClitnt.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string stringXml = webClitnt.DownloadString(strUrl);
            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(stringXml);
            string textTranslate = command.ResultSelector(document.Root);
            return textTranslate;
        }

    }

}
```

Использование в C# такое

```
        TranslateCommand translate = new TranslateCommand{
            Type = RequestType.Translate,
            Parameters = new Dictionary<string,string>{ {"lang", translateLanguage}, {"text", text} },
            ResultSelector = x => x.Element("text").Value
        };
        string result = api.GetResult(translate);
```

Пытаюсь писать на VB.

```
        Dim translate As TranslateCommand = New TranslateCommand()

        translate.Type = RequestType.Translate

        translate.Parameters = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        translate.Parameters.Add("lang", "EN")

        translate.ResultSelector = New Func(Of XElement, String)

        Dim result As String = api.GetResult(translate)
```

Предпоследняя строка, должна быть либо с AddressOF либо лямбда выражение.

```
translate.ResultSelector = New Func(Of XElement, String)
```

Как это `ResultSelector = x => x.Element("text").Value` применить правильно. Вынос мозга...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит обратиться к [справке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb531253.aspx)

Данная строка должна выглядеть примерно так:

```vb
translate.ResultSelector = Function(x) x.Element("text").Value
```

Comment: в том то и дело что на 10 раз перечитал и все равно не понимаю как оно должно быть :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim increment1 = Function(x) x + 1
```

См: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb531253.aspx

Comment: И к чему это тыкание в МСДН когда присутствует уже принятый ответ?